# Django Todo App - Filter by foreign keys results in TypeError

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

this is my model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Task(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

With the following view and URL pattern I get my the todos:

```
class TaskView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.all() ## get all todos
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

router.register("todos", views.TaskView)
```

However, I want the todos for a specific owner. I tried this:

```
class TaskView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.filter(id=id)
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

router.register("todos/<int:id>", views.TaskView)
```

This results in the following error:

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>.
```

using `get` instead of `filter` resulted in the same problem. Why does this error happen and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way: pass owner id in GET parms and filter this.

**serializers.py**:

```
class TaskView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        id = self.request.GET.get('owner_id')
        queryset = Task.objects.filter(owner__id=id)
        return queryset
```

**urls.py**:

```
router.register("todos", views.TaskView)
```

pass **owner_id** in `GET` query parms. :

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/todos/?owner_id=1

Answer (score 1):

Your model is :

```
class Task(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

So If you need all the task for a specific owner, your query should be :

```
Task.objects.filter(owner__id=id)
```

Considering id is the User's pk.

Comment: Plus the query needs to be in the `get_queryset` method of the view not directly on the class. (As the error describes `id` is simply the builtin id here)