# Django RESTApi Using ForeignKey as filter still produces error

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I think I come closer to my problem with API, but I still get the following error:

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>.
```

Model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Todos(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
    text = models.TextField(max_length=450, default="")
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Serializer:

```
class TodosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Todos
        fields = ("id", "owner", "name", "text", "done")
```

View:

```
class TodosView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Todos.objects.filter(owner__id=id)
    serializer_class = TodosSerializer
```

urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register("todos/<int:id>", views.TodosView)

urlpatterns = [path("", include(router.urls))]
```

I want to get all todos for a single User. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:

```
queryset = Todos.objects.filter(owner__id=1)
```

This actually does not produce an error. Something with my URL seems off:

```
http://localhost:8000/todos/%3Cint:id%3E/
```

Comment: Check out the docs on viewsets: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset
You'll want to override `get_queryset` in a similar way to the `AccountViewSet` example where you have access to the `request` and current user. You won't need to put any `id` in the url.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Todo App - Filter by foreign keys results in TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67225249/14131913)

Comment: no sorry, that results in the exact same error, I also tried that before. See my edit, the error seems to have a different source

Comment: I am pretty sure the erorr is caused in the URL: It looks like this: http://localhost:8000/todos/%3Cint:id%3E/

Comment: @DataMastery I think you are making a mistake in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67225249/14131913).It's fully works for me.Please do attention here remove `<int:pk>` in your `url` and put `id = self.request.GET.get('owner_id')` in `get_queryset` and then filter it. Then you need to pass **GET parms** like that `http://127.0.0.1:8000/todos/?owner_id=1`

Comment: now it´s working! Thanks. Changed your answer to accepted answer